# How to write a line-wise and column-wise sorted binary matrix/array?

Tags: c#, matrix, binary, iterator, logic

I am trying to write a iterator which generate MxN binary 2D-array like this:

1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
**0 0   1   1   1   1   1   1**

If we treat each line as a binary, E.g. **11111100**, each line is sorted from greater to less.

If we treat each column as a binary, E.g. **1110**, each column is sorted from greater to less.

The number of 0s, Z, is fixed.

iterator.Next() is supposed to be this one:

1   1   1   1   1   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   0   0   1   1
1   1   0   0   1   1   1   1
**1 0   1   0   1   1   1   1**

M,N,Z can be any reasonable value.

The problem is if I iterator each line, it's hard to look after each column, vice versa.

Time complexity should also be taken into consideration.

Comment: first question: is this some homework or would this algorithm have a reasonable appliance?

Comment: second question: the value of a line has to be unique inside the matrix?

Comment: first answer: AI project. This matrix is used to find all non-equivalent classes for sample selection.

Comment: second answer: Yes. Each line should be unique.

Comment: my approach would be to look at one line at first... try to treat it as a number... find all combinations that would match the given Z

Comment: after that you simply have to combine those numbers for it matches the second criterea...

Answer (score 1):

This is my first shot, the GetPossibleLines() Method is not really performant.
However if you solve that the second problem solves itself:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Possible combinations with m=8, z=2");

        var possibleLines = GetPossibleLines(8, 2).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < possibleLines.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < possibleLines[i].Length; j++)
            {
                Console.Write(possibleLines[i][j] ? 1 : 0);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("------------------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("And the Matrices:");

        foreach (var matrix in GetMatrices(8,5,2))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < matrix.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < matrix[i].Length; j++)
                {
                    Console.Write(matrix[i][j] ? 1 : 0);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }

            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------------");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("---------------End------------------");

    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool[][]> GetMatrices(int m, int n, int z)
    {
        var possibleLines = GetPossibleLines(m, z).ToArray();

        var lineCombinations = GetPossibleLines(possibleLines.Length, n).ToArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < lineCombinations.Length; i++)
        {
            int combinationIndex = 0;
            bool[][] result = new bool[n][];
            for (int j = 0; j < lineCombinations[i].Length; j++)
            {
                if (!lineCombinations[i][j])
                {
                    result[combinationIndex++]= possibleLines[j];
                }
            }
            yield return result;

        }
    }

    private static IEnumerable<bool[]> GetPossibleLines(int m, int z)
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < Math.Pow(2, m); i++)
        {
            var remainder = i;
            var remainingZ = z;
            bool[] result = new bool[m];
            for (int j = 0; j < m && remainingZ > -1; j++)
            {
                bool b = remainder % 2 == 1;
                result[j] = b;
                remainder /= 2;
                if (!b)
                {
                    remainingZ--;
                }
            }
            if (remainder == 0 && remainingZ == 0)
            {
                yield return result;
            }
        }
    }
}
```